# Make a method report progress in Winform C#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have two classes, form1.cs and test.cs

Form1.cs calls some public method in test.cs. Is it possible to somehow make the program report the progress?

For example,

In Form1.cs

```
test.CallTestMethod();
```

In test.cs

```
public void CallTestMethod()
{
    // Read excel file line by line (~5000 lines)
    // I used double for loops to iterate row and col
}
```

I know how to report progress if the method is in the form element, but how would I report progress if im calling an external method? Is it even possible?

Thanks

Comment: If you wish to update a TextBox for example, you can pass it as a variable into the method

Comment: You mean pass the Textbox as a variable? or pass some integer value as ref and update the textbox as the integer value changes?

Comment: @djskj189 Ignore that idea, it's not a good idea.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're going to need `CallTestMethod()` to execute in a non-UI thread. give it a parameter `Action<double> reportProgressPercent`. Have it call `reportProgressPercent` as appropriate. When `Form1` calls `CallTestMethod()`, have it pass in an appropriate lambda that invokes into the UI thread to report progress.

```
public void CallTestMethod(Action<double> reportProgressPcnt)
{
    foreach (var blah in whatever)
    {
        foreach (var foo in innerLoopWhatever)
        {
            //  do stuff. On every nth iteration or whatever, figure out what 
            //  your completed percentage is and pass it to reportProgressPcnt
            double progress = (curRow / totalRows) * 100;
            reportProgressPcnt(progress);
        }
    }
}
```

Form1.cs

```
progBar1.Maximum = 100;
progBar1.Step = 1;

Task.Run(() => {
    test.CallTestMethod(pcnt => {
        Invoke(new Action(() => progBar1.Value = (int)pcnt));
    })
});
```

If you want to report progress in some other way, change the parameters to your `Action`; for example:

```
public void CallTestMethod(Action<int, int> reportCurrentRowAndColumn)
{
    int curRow = 0;
    int curCol = 0;

    //...blah blah loop stuff, update values of curRow & curCol as needed...
            reportCurrentRowAndColumn(curRow, curCol);
```

Then maybe your `Action` could update a pair of labels displaying current row and current column.

Comment: Ive never seen Action<T> before so it might be a dumb question, but how do I pass the value to the Action<T>?? Do i just do something like reportProgressPcnt = someVal ?

Comment: @djskj189 It's a lambda. You call it like a method -- will update answer.

Comment: @djskj189 Updated.